# Erro ao receber json de webhook

Tags: javascript, google

Estou tentando utilizar o Google Script para fazer uma solicitação a um webhook e retornar ele para uma planilha no Google Sheets.

Estou recebendo o seguinte quando tento debugar as função *post*:

**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined (linha 10, arquivo "Code")"**

eis o código:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID DA PLANILHA');
script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Leads');
  
 
  var requestData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var leadData = requestData.leads;
  

  var trava = LockService.getScriptLock();
  trava.waitLock(2000);
  

  var values = []
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var JSONSource = JSON.stringify(requestData);
  
 
  for (var i = 0; i < leadData.length; i++) {
    values.push([JSONSource,
                 timestamp,
                 leadData[i].email,
                 leadData[i].personal_phone,
                 leadData[i].name,
                 leadData[i].job_title,
                 leadData[i].custom_fields["nome do campo personalizado"],
                 leadData[i].custom_fields["nome do outro campo personalizado"],
                 leadData[i].first_conversion.content.identificador,
                 leadData[i].first_conversion.conversion_origin.source,
                 leadData[i].first_conversion.conversion_origin.medium]);
  }
  
 
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  

  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), values[0].length + 1).setFormulaR1C1("if(countif(mqlEmails;R[0]C[-9])>0;\"MQL\";\"Lead\")");
  // Fórmula para identificar se lead também é Oportunidade
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), values[0].length + 2).setFormulaR1C1("if(countif(oppEmails;R[0]C[-10])>0;\"Opp\";\"Lead\")");
  
  trava.releaseLock();
  return "OK";
}

function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h2>Get request recebida.</h2><p>Essa função te ajuda a identificar se o Web App da integração está ativo.</p>");
}
```

Comment: Tente melhora sua pergunta assim você evita a chuva de votos negativos aqui. vejo o [LINK](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Provavelmente você está rodando o código diretamente do editor de scripts, não está? Você precisa implantar o script como um Aplicativo Web e o acessar por sua url através de um navegador ou curl. Veja as [instruções de como implantar um script como aplicativo web](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

Answer (score 1):

Qual é o conteúdo do objeto "e"?

Qual é a linha 10?

---

Presumindo que a linha 10 seja esta:

```
var requestData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); var leadData = requestData.leads;
```

O objeto **e** não tem o atributo **postData** porque ele é indefinido. Em algum lugar antes desta linha no código tu deveria ter um teste pra ver se o objeto foi criado ou se a função que cria ele teve algum erro.